# Passport.js, Express.js, and Angular.js routing: how can they coexist?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I apologize this question turned out a bit long, but I have worked on this for some time and really needed to explain all the story.

**Background**: App based on MEAN stack, trying to *authorize* Facebook logins using Passport.js.

Following Passport.js [guide](http://passportjs.org/guide/facebook/) I implemented something similar to:

```
// HTML
    <a href="/connect/facebook" target="_self">Add a Facebook login</a>
// send to facebook to do the authentication
app.get('/connect/facebook',isLoggedIn, passport.authorize('facebook', 
    { scope : 'email' })
);
// handle the callback after facebook has authorized the user
app.get('/connect/facebook/callback',
    passport.authorize('facebook', {
    successRedirect : '/profile',
    failureRedirect : '/profile'
    }));
```

Notice the `target=_self` in the html in order to skip Angular routing. 
Clearly, authorization works fine. However, redirection does not work, as the routing is handled by Angular. After authorization I never land on `/profile` (but on the default Angular route).

Therefore, I tried with a custom callback as suggested by Passport.js [here](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/), with the hope of passing json data to Angular, and let Angular do the routing. I ended up doing something like:

```
// In the controller
$http.get("/connect/facebook").success(function(data){
    // here I wait for json data from the server and do the routing
});
// I call this route from Angular
app.get('/connect/facebook',isLoggedIn,passport.authorize('facebook', 
    { scope : 'email' })
);
// But Facebook lands here!
app.get('/connect/facebook/callback',function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authorize('facebook', function(err, user, info) {
        res.json({something:smtg});
        ...
```

Clearly custom callbacks work for local-login, as Passport.js explains. But here do you see the problem? I call `/connect/facebook` from Angular, but I should receive some json from `/connect/facebook/callback`.

I am about to give up Passport, but before this, do you see any solution which would allow landing on `/profile` after FB authorization, perhaps with a custom message? Many thanks for reading through.

**EDIT**: 
The same question had been reported as an issue on the [Passport-Facebook GitHub account](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/106). Some additional attempts have been posted there, but not quite the fix yet.

Comment: How's redirection intercepted by Angular? Do you have the `'/profile'` route defined in your Express app? What does it serve?

Comment: I have a `/profile` route in Angular, no `/profile` route in Express, and an `app.get('*',..)` route in Express. It serves the default route in angular: `.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});`. 
Any attempt to use `res.render` or `res.redirect(to a specific angular view)` from Express is vain.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit more in depth than can be described in one answer, but I'll try to start pointing you in the right direction.

Essentially, Angular.js routes are not really HTML routes at all, but an internal route structure that happens to use the URL for use of the end user.  Remember that Angular.js is a client script, and that a full page reload is not desired, as this will reload the entire script.  Therefore, `/#` is used to *trick* the browser into jumping to a specific bit of code within the already loaded script. (as opposed to the traditional anchor location in the HTML document).  Unfortunately (or fortunately), HTML 5 mode allows you to hide the `/#` part of the url, so instead of seeing `http://somesite.com/#/someroute` you just see `http://somesite.com/someroute`.  Rest assured, however, that the `/#` is still there.  Angular.js uses the HTML5 pushState (AKA [HistoryAPI](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#history)) to perform the magic replacement.

Given this, if you have called a server route, you are outside the Angular.js script, and any call to load the angular script again will start from the very beginning.  You can't actually call your Angular.js route from the server without a full reload.  Therefore, you are really doing a double route redirect here. Your server should be calling it's default route for angular, appending `/#/someroute` to the call.  The angular.js page will load, parse off the `/#`, and redirect to the correct angular route.  Keep in mind, however, that if there was any dependency on already loaded objects, those are no longer in memory.  Therefore, any route accessed this way should operate as if it is an entry point to your application.

Effectively, you should try using `successRedirect : '#/profile'`, keeping in mind that the `profile` route in angular should be treated as an app entry point.

Hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried what you suggested, i.e., using `#/profile`, but with little luck. I notice from the logger on the server that the route `/profile` (or `#/profile`) is never called. 
I doubted it was because Express does not have such route, so I implemented a simple route `app.get('/profile', function(req,res){res.render(some html page);}`. Also in this case no luck.

Comment: plus one for referencing the pushState api. didn't know how routing worked in angular!

Answer (score 0):

If @Claies's way is not working, is it possible you have not get rid of the #*=* fragment from the facebook callback.

Have a read of [this post](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/106)

Comment: Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. to improve your answer read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer